# Converting and size reduction of .m2t video for Flickr?

Tags: video, compression, video-conversion

I have a .m2t video file that I would like to upload to Flickr.

Can someone advise the best way to go about reducing the file size to <1gb and changing the file type to one that is accepted by Flickr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For conversion and compression you can use HandBrake.

```
sudo apt-get install HandBrake
```

Or [download it from the website.](https://handbrake.fr/downloads.php%20.)

To reduce the size use a good compression algorithm like H.264.